# how to fix the interface of this (simple html/css)

Tags: html, css

here is my interface
[image: here is my interface]

I have two blocks `div.small` (include 4 small articles) and `article.big`. I want the big block to be to the right of the small block, but it's underneath.

```css
*{
font-family: tahoma;
}

div.all{
    height: 528px;
    width: 824px;
}
article.small{
    width: 312px;
    height: 82px;
}
div.small{
    float: left;
}
img.smallimg{
    float: left;
    width: 121px;
    height: 82px;
}
article.big{
    width: 496px;
    height: 525px;
}
img.bigimg{
    width: 494px;
    height: 329px;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
<div class="small">
<article class="small">
    <a href=""><img src="small01.jpg" alt="" class = "smallimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="samlllink">Link 01</a>
</article>

<article class="small">
    <a href=""><img src="small02.jpg" alt="" class="smallimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="samlllink">link 02</a>
</article>

<article class="small">
    <a href=""><img src="small03.jpg" alt="" class="smallimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="samlllink">link03</a>
</article>

<article class="small">
    <a href=""><img src="small04.jpg" alt="" class="smallimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="samlllink">link04</a>
</article>

<article class="small">
    <a href=""><img src="small02.jpg" alt="" class="smallimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="samlllink">link05</a>
</article>
</div>

<article class="big">
    <a href=""><img src="big.jpg" alt="" class="bigimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="biglink">big link</a>

</article>
</div>
```

I've tried to limit `div.all` with height = 528px, however, the `article.big` should've to be to the right, but it's not. My question is: Why's my way wrong?

Comment: You can try adding 'float: left' to your article.big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice removal of floats (redundant) and addition of `display: flex` which displays in child elements as a row by default. The reason your big div is underneath is because the elements being used `div` are block level elements by default. If they were `inline-block` they would also align side by side. Cheers!

```css
*{
font-family: tahoma;
}

div.all{
    height: 528px;
    width: 824px;
    display: flex;
}
article.small{
    width: 312px;
    height: 82px;
}

img.smallimg{
    width: 121px;
    height: 82px;
}
article.big{
    width: 496px;
    height: 525px;
}
img.bigimg{
    width: 494px;
    height: 329px;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
<div class="small">
<article class="small">
    <a href=""><img src="small01.jpg" alt="" class = "smallimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="samlllink">Link 01</a>
</article>

<article class="small">
    <a href=""><img src="small02.jpg" alt="" class="smallimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="samlllink">link 02</a>
</article>

<article class="small">
    <a href=""><img src="small03.jpg" alt="" class="smallimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="samlllink">link03</a>
</article>

<article class="small">
    <a href=""><img src="small04.jpg" alt="" class="smallimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="samlllink">link04</a>
</article>

<article class="small">
    <a href=""><img src="small02.jpg" alt="" class="smallimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="samlllink">link05</a>
</article>
</div>

<article class="big">
    <a href=""><img src="big.jpg" alt="" class="bigimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="biglink">big link</a>

</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is  this what you want? No complicated `display: flex;` needed

```css
*{
font-family: tahoma;
}

div.all{
    height: 528px;
    width: 824px;
}
article.small{
    width: 312px;
    height: 82px;
}
div.small{
    float: left;
}
img.smallimg{
    float: left;
    width: 121px;
    height: 82px;
}
article.big{
    width: 496px;
    height: 525px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
img.bigimg{
    width: 494px;
    height: 329px;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
<div class="small">
<article class="small">
    <a href=""><img src="small01.jpg" alt="" class = "smallimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="samlllink">Link 01</a>
</article>

<article class="small">
    <a href=""><img src="small02.jpg" alt="" class="smallimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="samlllink">link 02</a>
</article>

<article class="small">
    <a href=""><img src="small03.jpg" alt="" class="smallimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="samlllink">link03</a>
</article>

<article class="small">
    <a href=""><img src="small04.jpg" alt="" class="smallimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="samlllink">link04</a>
</article>

<article class="small">
    <a href=""><img src="small02.jpg" alt="" class="smallimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="samlllink">link05</a>
</article>
</div>

<article class="big">
    <a href=""><img src="big.jpg" alt="" class="bigimg"></a>
    <a href="" class="biglink">big link</a>

</article>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `absolute` will start to get complicated when the width of the viewport changes and the "big" div overlaps the left content. Just FYI

Comment: @ChrisW. That's totally true. But all I can see is fixed `height`s and `width`s

Comment: Ya but when you throw absolute at it here the `relative` position parent is the window either way, so when it's `absolute` it's removed from the normal DOM flow and those hard set widths aren't respected except on the elements they're applied to, open up your example full page and narrow the window width to see what I mean.